# short doesn't overflow visual c++ 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, integer-overflow, short

Input of 32760 and 9 print out 32769, not -32767.

I don't know what else to do, it's a simple program, but it doesn't work as I want.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    short a, b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cout << a+b;
}
```

Comment: Check the maximum value that `short` can hold, with `std::numeric_limits<short>::max()`. It can be larger than 16 bits, so that arithmetic might not overflow. Note, also, that if it does overflow, the result is undefined; it is not required to wrap around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the arithmetic operation `a+b` is not of type `short`. Instead the rules of [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) have it that the operands are first promoted to a larger integer type before addition.

To make it "*work"* as you want, then something like this will force integer overflow (that you seem to want to see):

```
short x = a + b;
cout << x;
```

Comment: Also, `short` could be large enough to hold the result of that addition. `short` is required to be **at least** 16 bits wide, but it can be larger. +1.